# Problem with iPhone LCD after repair

Tags: iphone

I have repaired an iPhone with a 3GS glass. Then I realized it was for an iPhone 3G. So, after replacing it again with a proper 3G glass the LCD just went black! What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem before, when I replaced a cracked iPhone screen for a friend. When a 3GS digitalizer gets in contact with an iPhone 3G LCD they send the wrong signals to the motherboard(through ribbon cable 3) and then the graphic part of the motherboard brokes. So you will probably have to replace the whole motherboard, be more careful when buying new glass next time, check the modelnumber first!

Comment: Than you very much for your help!